# how to index (or view ) two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, view

```
aid  |  name                   udi | aid | name | description
------------------------      -------------------------
1       text                   1     1      text     text
```

I want merge these tables in one table (with realtime update)

how can I do it with index like these:

```
aid | aname |  uid | uname | udescription
```

Comment: `create view . . . from t1 join t2 on t1.aid = t2.aid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create view YOURviewName as   

select
a.aid,
a.name as aname,
u.aid as uid,
u.name as uname,
u.description as udescription
from
a inner join u on a.aid = u.aid
```